# Forward-pass for PyTorch Module in Cython

Tags: pytorch, list-comprehension, cython, tensor, torch

I am creating a neural network for DeepSet where each element in the set is itself a set. Since these sets are not vectorizable I am representing my input as lists of lists of torch.tensors.

For the forward-pass of my network I don't think there is any alternative to using for-loops/list comprehension. Potentially these for-loops iterate a relatively big number of times. As such, training my networks is very time consuming since they are running in Python.

I have tried with TorchScript, without a major improvement in runningtime (about 40% improved runningtime). I hope that re-writing my loops in Cython might yield better reuslts. However I can't figure out how to combine nn.Modules from PyTorch with Cython. Any suggestions?

Here is my module:

```py
class DSSN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, pd_rho, dh_rho, fc_network, device):

        super(DSSN, self).__init__()

        self.pers_lay1 = pd_rho
        self.pers_lay2 = dh_rho
        self.fc = fc_network

    def forward(self:nn.Module, x:List[List[torch.Tensor]]) -> torch.Tensor: 

        x = torch.stack([torch.stack([self.pers_lay1(pd) for pd in sample]) for sample in x])
        x = self.pers_lay2(x)
        x = self.fc(x)

        return x
```